# Using Entity Framework, non-MVC project, need help with class structure

Tags: class-design, entity-framework

I'm working on a very large non-MVC project utilizing Entity Framework for database access.  This is a new project, so we've got a wide-open canvas for development.

The conceptual problem I'm running into is how to model the layer just above the EF Models.

At the database level I've got a `Customer`, `Order`, and `Item` table so there's a model for each.

Now I need to describe what the Customer can *do*.  For example, ultimately I want to say something like:

```
 Order newOrder = customerObject.CreateOrder(itemList);
```

Where does the method CreateOrder live?

My gut tells me that there's a sub-class of the `Customer` Model that has the methods needed by the Customer.  With an interface to that class up front to keep the cross-dependencies between modules low.

But this sounds too easy to be the correct way.

Some related questions I've found, but didn't exactly apply are:

- [Different kind of problem, and the proposed solution is to make the models into partial classes](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/291710/class-structure-for-entity-framework)
- [This is discussing the full layer management, and obviously a smaller problem](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/126285/entity-framework-and-layer-separation)

Comment: http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html

Answer (score 2):

The one that I have used which worked quite nicely. Basically used repositories to house the methods called. Everything was divided into:

- Context: Sets up your db context using the below, implements `System.Data.Entity.DbContext`. It contains `DbSet`'s of your entities. So a sample will look like below:

  ```
  public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }

  protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) 
  {
      Database.SetInitializer<CustomerDatabaseContext>(null);

      modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new CustomerConfiguration()); 
  }
  ```
- Entities: Literal mapping of db object

  ```
  public class Customer
  {
      public long Id {get; set;}

      public string Name {get; set;}
  }
  ```
- Configurations: Setting up your entity

  ```
  public class CustomerConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Customer>
  {
      public CustomerConfiguration()
      {
          this.Property(x => x.Id).HasColumnName("CustomerId");
          this.HasKey(x => x.Id);
          this.Property(x => x.Name);
      }
  }
  ```
- Repositories: Holds all the methods e.g.

  ```
  public Customer GetById(long identity)
  {
      using (var context = CustomerDatabaseContext.Start())
      {
          return context.Customers.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == identity);
      }
  }
  ```
- The repositories are initialised in code and used e.g.

  ```
  var customer = this.repository.GetById(request.CustomerId);
  ```

Comment: IMHO, repository pattern (atop EF which _is already a repository_) is redundant. I feel this would be better served as a service (which accepts a repository, or, in this case, the EF context).

Comment: Ah hang on that time we did code first, are you importing the model?

Comment: This project is strictly DB first.  We've got one of those cases where the DB has to be designed *very* carefully.  The models we're just pulling in from the DB as-is pretty much.

Comment: Hmmm I had a project like that as well, just can't remember as well. Pretty sure we extended the partial repositories? Will give it some thought though.

Answer (score 1):

Everyone appears to be on the repository train. Given EF is already a repository, I would push to house business logic on a service layer. A service doesn't necessarily have to be in a new library (though it could), but does provide that additional logic atop the base entities. To illustrate:

```
public interface IOrderService : IDisposable
{
    Order Create(Customer customer, params Item[] items);
}

public class OrderService : IOrderService
{
    private DbContext context;

    public OrderService(DbContext context)
    {
        Contract.Requires(context != null);

        this.context = context;
    }

    public Order Create(Customer customer, params Item[] items)
    {
        Contract.Requires(customer != null);
        Contract.Requires(items != null);
        Contract.Requires(items.Length > 0);
        Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<Order>() != null);

        Order order;

        //
        // Business logic building order;
        //

        return order;
    }
}
```

Then usage would look something like:

```
// -- Existing variables --
var db = /* your EF context */;
var customer = /* your targetted customer */;
var items = /* the items to be added */;
// -- /Existing variables --

// Executing against new service
var orderSvc = new OrderService(db);
var newOrder = orderSvc.Create(customer, items);
```

*Commentary*

All a repository pattern does (on top of an ORM) is abstract out the API that's already there. Now you're duplicating efforts, and, a lot of the time, losing some very cool features of the ORM itself (this *is* why you chose the ORM over using `SqlConnection` I would presume...). Sure, you *might* change out your ORM months/years from now, but is it worth the up-front effort? (That's for you to decide)

Comment: "Given EF is already a repository ..." Here is my opinion on how [EF is not a Repository](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13189143/18938). Having said that, I would probably do something much like your answer. :-)

Comment: A service layer would be adequate for us, more abstractions aren't really necessary at this level in this project.  We are effectively supplying just a business-layer API.  I'll read up on this particular pattern, but it sounds like a good start.

Comment: As a followup, in this pattern what would you do when you needed Order to do something?  Maybe to (later) compute the order total or discounts?  Would you have to extent the Order class, or would you call the OrderService passing in the order as the first argument?

Comment: IMHO, keep the entities POCOs and apply any kind of logic (like what you've mentioned) in a service. That said, also keep similar logic tied by a single unit of work (Order service should do things related to orders, Customer service may update customer email, etc.). And, yes, passing in the Order is acceptable.